# Spatial database architecture with Apache Parquet, PostgresSQL and PostGIS on on-premises bare-metal S3/MinIo cluster

Tags: postgresql, postgis, parquet, minio

Designing storage architecture for Petabyte-scale geospatial data; starting from scratch. Creating a [MinIo](https://min.io/) cluster to store the objects in S3 buckets. To store the metadata, I’m considering the Apache Parquet format managed by PostgresSQL, extended by PostGIS.
Using Parquet implies resourcing to a PostgresSQL FDW (foreign data wrapper) - ParquetS3.
No doubts regarding Parquet’s main advantages when compared to "pure" PostgresSQL: higher query speed, higher compression rate, and the ability to store in S3, which for us is a significant advantage.
However, I cannot find documentation or a use case of Parquet with geospatial data.

Should I worry about losing geospatial query features (the PostGIS support) due to the use of Parquet or it’s wrapper for PostgreSQL - ParquetS3?

According to [PostgreSQL’s documentation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers), the wrapper ParquetS3 is valid for PostgreSQL, but I see no mention to the extension PostGIS. On this same PostgreSQL FDW list, there are some geo data wrappers, but these aren’t meant to use use S3/MinIo.
According to [PostGIS documentation](https://postgis.net/2014/12/19/postgis_fdw/#:%7E:text=Foreign%20data%20wrappers%20allow%20you,for%20accessing%20remote%20PostgreSQL%20servers.), PostGIS ships with two FWD (Oracle FDW and OGR FDW), but this is a post from 2014.

The [code repository](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw) for OGR FDW reads:

> OGR is the vector half of the GDAL spatial data access library. It
> allows access to a large number of GIS data formats using a simple C
> API for data reading and writing. Since OGR exposes a simple table
> structure and PostgreSQL foreign data wrappers allow access to table
> structures, the fit seems pretty perfect.

This is followed by a list of limitations of the implementation.

Does the OGR FDW work below the ParquetS3 one, despite the limitations listed?
Does anyone know of a FDW for geo data (PostGIS), that also allows sourcing from MinIo S3 buckets? With Parquet or equivalent?
Or has anyone tested the configuration above?

I always have the alternative of creating the data store of the PostgreSQL/PostGIS outside of S3, but I’d rather have it in the MinIo cluster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for Parquet, there is a special format for geospatial data called [geoparquet](https://github.com/opengeospatial/geoparquet) created by Open Geospatial Consortium.

Based on this [answer](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31276405), geoparquet embeds it's geo data as WKB so it should be straightforward to use it in PostGIS. However official documentation currently mentions integration only with geopandas python library, sfarrow R library and GDAL/OGR tools.

Worst-case scenario - you'd have to write a python script for digesting data from S3 and uploading it into PostGIS in some form of ETL (maybe with Apache Airflow).